# The Mahalanobis distance between a point and the mean vector is always the same

Tags: java, data-mining, mahout, data-cleaning, mahalanobis

I‘m trying to perform some data cleansing algorithm recently. When I try to calculate the mahalanobis distance between points in the data set and the mean vector, it seems the same.

For example, I have a data set like:

```
{{2,2,3},{4,5,9},{7,8,9}}
```

The mean vector is :

```
{13/3,5,7}
```

And the covariance matrix is:

```
{{6.333333333333333,7.5,7.0},{7.5,9.0,9.0},{7.0,9.0,12.0}}
```

Then the distances between {2,2,3}, {4,5,9}, {7,8,9} and the mean vector are all 8290542, which is quite strange. After calculating on paper, the result is the same.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code or thought? I'd be more than grateful if someone could help me out. Following is some code I used in dealing with this problem.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.Covariance;
import org.apache.mahout.math.*;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.MahalanobisDistanceMeasure;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = {2,2,3};
        Vector aVector = new DenseVector(a);

        double[] b = {4,5,9};
        Vector bVector = new DenseVector(b);

        double[] c = {7,8,9};
        Vector cVector = new DenseVector(b);


        double[] mean = {13/3,5,7};
        Vector meanVector = new DenseVector(mean);

        MahalanobisDistanceMeasure measure = new MahalanobisDistanceMeasure();

        double[][] ma = {{2,2,3},{4,5,9},{7,8,9}};
        RealMatrix matrix = new Covariance(ma).getCovarianceMatrix();
        Matrix math = new DenseMatrix(matrix.getData());

        measure.setCovarianceMatrix(math);

        measure.setMeanVector(meanVector);
        System.out.println(matrix.toString());
        System.out.println(measure.distance(meanVector,cVector));

    }


}
```

Comment: Third new should say new dense vector of c I think, but you repeated b

Comment: Also 13/3 might be evaluating to 4. You might need 13.0/4.0 or 13.0d/4.0d

Comment: @JeremyKahan Though I update my code like you said, the Mahalanobis distance is still the same for a,b and c.

Comment: I published example of code how to calculate the Mahalanobis distance without using apache.mahout lib.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233869/calclulate-the-mahalanobis-distance-with-org-apache-commons-math3-only/69233870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *need* to use more data.

The mean vector + covariance matrix will otherwise **overfit** to your data, and give the same distance each.

For 3d data, use at least 20 points.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used real data set and it worked.